# Node cannot be cast to java.util.Map. AStart implementation

Tags: java, dictionary, nodes, a-star

I'm having some problems implementing AStar or A* algorithm for practice, it looks like the code is all good just when i try to do some tests it crashes on

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: AStar.Node cannot be cast to java.util.Map
at AStar.GraphAStar.addNode(GraphAStar.java:51)
at AStar.AStar.main(AStar.java:283)
```

It looks like the casting doesn't quite work as it says on GraphAStar class specifictly  in this line.

```
nodeIdNode.put(nodeId, (Map<T, Double>) new Node<T>(nodeId, heuristicMap.get(nodeId)));
```

Any ideas???

I'm adding my code down here.

Node class

```
public class Node <T> {

T nodeId;
Map<T, Double> heuristic;

double g; //distance to new node
double h; //distante to goal
double f; // f = g + h;

public Node(T nodeId,Map<T,Double> heuristic){
    this.nodeId = nodeId;
    this.g = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    this.heuristic = heuristic;
}

public T getNode(){
    return nodeId;
}

public double getGPath(){
    return g;
}

public void setGPath(double g){
    this.g = g;
}

public void CalculateF(T destination){
    this.h = heuristic.get(destination);
    this.f = g + h;
}

public double getH(){
    return g;
}

public double getF(){
    return f;
}


}
```

GraphAStar class

```
public class GraphAStar<T> implements Iterable<T> {
/***
 * A map from the Node id to outgoing edge.
 * An outgoing edge is represented as a Node and the length
 */
Map<T, Map<Node<T>, Double>> graph;
/***
 * A map of heuristic from a node to each other node in the graph
 */
Map<T, Map<T,Double>> heuristicMap;
/***
 * A map between the Node id and its data.
 */
Map<T, Map<T,Double>> nodeIdNode;

public GraphAStar(Map<T, Map<T,Double>> heuristicMap){
    if(heuristicMap == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("The heuristic map should not be null");
    }
    graph = new HashMap<T, Map<Node<T>, Double>>();
    nodeIdNode = new HashMap<>();
    this.heuristicMap = heuristicMap;
}

/***
 * Adds a new node to the graph
 * Internally it creates the Node and populate the heuristic map with node input to node data
 * @param nodeId the node to be added
 */
public void addNode(T nodeId){
    if(nodeId == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("The node cannot be null");
    }
    if(!heuristicMap.containsKey(nodeId)){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("This node is not part of the heuristic Map");
    }
    graph.put(nodeId, new HashMap<Node<T>,Double>());
    nodeIdNode.put(nodeId, (Map<T, Double>) new Node<T>(nodeId, heuristicMap.get(nodeId)));
}



/***
 * Adds an edge from source node to destination node
 * there can only be a single edge from source to node.
 * Adding additional  edge would be overwrite the value.
 * @param From     the first node to be in the edge
 * @param To       the second node to be in the edge
 * @param length   the length of node From and To
 */
public void addEdge(T From, T To, double length){
    if(From == null || To == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Either of the nodes cannot be null");
    }
    if(!heuristicMap.containsKey(To) || !heuristicMap.containsKey(From)){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Either of the nodes should be listed in the heuristic map");
    }
    if(!graph.containsKey(To) || !graph.containsKey(From)){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Either of the nodes should be part of the graph");
    }
    graph.get(From).put((Node<T>) nodeIdNode.get(To), length);
    graph.get(To).put((Node<T>) nodeIdNode.get(From), length);
}
/***
 * Returns immutable view of edges  
 * @param nodeId the node whose outgoing needs to be returned.
 * @return       An immutable view of the edges leaving that node.
 */
public Map<Node<T>,Double> edgesFrom(T nodeId){
    if(nodeId == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("The input node should not be null");
    }
    if(!heuristicMap.containsKey(nodeId)){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("This node should be part of the heuristic map");
    }
    if(!graph.containsKey(nodeId)){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Thsi node should be null");
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(graph.get(nodeId));
}
/***
 * the node data corresponding  to the current nodeId
 * @param nodeId  the nodeId to be returned
 * @return        the node data from the node
 */
public Node<T> getNodeData(T nodeId){
    if(nodeId == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("The node should not be empty");
    }
    if(!nodeIdNode.containsKey(nodeId)){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("The node does not exist");
    }
    return (Node<T>) nodeIdNode.get(nodeId);
}

/***
 * Returns an iterator  that can  traverse  the nodes of the graph
 * @return an iterator
 */
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return graph.keySet().iterator();
}


}
```

AStar class

```
public class AStar<T> {

GraphAStar<T> graph;

public AStar(GraphAStar<T> graphA){
    this.graph = graphA;
}

//extends comparator
public class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node<T>>{

    public int compare(Node<T> first,Node<T> second){
        if(first.getF() > second.getF()){
            return 1;
        }
        if(second.getF() > first.getF()){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public List<T> Astar(T source, T destination){
    Queue<Node<T>> openQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node<T>>(11,new NodeComparator());

    Node<T> sourceNode = graph.getNodeData(source);
    sourceNode.setGPath(0);
    sourceNode.CalculateF(destination);
    openQueue.add(sourceNode);

    Map<T, T> path = new HashMap<T, T>();
    Set<Node<T>> closedList = new HashSet<Node<T>>();

    while(!openQueue.isEmpty()){
        Node<T> node = openQueue.poll();

        if(node.getNode().equals(destination)){
            return path(path,destination);
        }

        closedList.add(node);

        for(Entry<Node<T>, Double> neighborEntry : graph.edgesFrom(node.getNode()).entrySet()){
            Node<T> neighbor = neighborEntry.getKey();

            if(closedList.contains(neighbor)){
                continue;
            }
            double distanceBetweenTwoNodes = neighborEntry.getValue();
            double tentativeG = distanceBetweenTwoNodes + node.getGPath();

            if(tentativeG < neighbor.getGPath()){
                neighbor.setGPath(tentativeG);
                neighbor.CalculateF(destination);

                path.put(neighbor.getNode(), node.getNode());
                if(!openQueue.contains(neighbor)){
                    openQueue.add(neighbor);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}

private List<T> path(Map<T,T> path, T destination){
    assert path != null;
    assert destination  != null;

    List<T> pathList = new ArrayList<T>();
    pathList.add(destination);
    while(path.containsKey(destination)){
        destination = path.get(destination);
        pathList.add(destination);
    }
    Collections.reverse(pathList);
    return pathList;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String, Map<String,Double>> heuristic = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Double>>();

    //distance from Node N to all
    Map<String, Double> MapA = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapA.put("A", 0.0);
    MapA.put("B", 2.0);
    MapA.put("C", 3.0);
    MapA.put("D", 5.0);
    MapA.put("E", 7.0);
    MapA.put("F", 4.0);
    MapA.put("G", 10.0);
    MapA.put("H", 13.0);
    MapA.put("I", 15.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapB = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapB.put("A", 2.0);
    MapB.put("B", 0.0);
    MapB.put("C", 5.0);
    MapB.put("D", 3.0);
    MapB.put("E", 4.0);
    MapB.put("F", 6.0);
    MapB.put("G", 6.0);
    MapB.put("H", 10.0);
    MapB.put("I", 14.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapC = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapC.put("A", 3.0);
    MapC.put("B", 5.0);
    MapC.put("C", 0.0);
    MapC.put("D", 4.0);
    MapC.put("E", 7.0);
    MapC.put("F", 2.0);
    MapC.put("G", 10.0);
    MapC.put("H", 7.0);
    MapC.put("I", 15.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapD = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapD.put("A", 5.0);
    MapD.put("B", 5.0);
    MapD.put("C", 4.0);
    MapD.put("D", 0.0);
    MapD.put("E", 3.0);
    MapD.put("F", 3.0);
    MapD.put("G", 7.0);
    MapD.put("H", 9.0);
    MapD.put("I", 11.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapE = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapE.put("A", 7.0);
    MapE.put("B", 4.0);
    MapE.put("C", 7.0);
    MapE.put("D", 3.0);
    MapE.put("E", 0.0);
    MapE.put("F", 9.0);
    MapE.put("G", 2.0);
    MapE.put("H", 11.0);
    MapE.put("I", 9.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapF = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapF.put("A", 4.0);
    MapF.put("B", 6.0);
    MapF.put("C", 2.0);
    MapF.put("D", 3.0);
    MapF.put("E", 9.0);
    MapF.put("F", 0.0);
    MapF.put("G", 7.0);
    MapF.put("H", 3.0);
    MapF.put("I", 7.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapG = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapG.put("A", 10.0);
    MapG.put("B", 6.0);
    MapG.put("C", 10.0);
    MapG.put("D", 7.0);
    MapG.put("E", 2.0);
    MapG.put("F", 7.0);
    MapG.put("G", 0.0);
    MapG.put("H", 5.0);
    MapG.put("I", 2.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapH = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapH.put("A", 13.0);
    MapH.put("B", 10.0);
    MapH.put("C", 7.0);
    MapH.put("D", 9.0);
    MapH.put("E", 11.0);
    MapH.put("F", 3.0);
    MapH.put("G", 5.0);
    MapH.put("H", 0.0);
    MapH.put("I", 4.0);

    Map<String, Double> MapI = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    MapI.put("A", 15.0);
    MapI.put("B", 14.0);
    MapI.put("C", 15.0);
    MapI.put("D", 11.0);
    MapI.put("E", 9.0);
    MapI.put("F", 7.0);
    MapI.put("G", 2.0);
    MapI.put("H", 4.0);
    MapI.put("I", 0.0);

    heuristic.put("A", MapA);
    heuristic.put("B", MapB);
    heuristic.put("C", MapC);
    heuristic.put("D", MapD);
    heuristic.put("E", MapE);
    heuristic.put("F", MapF);
    heuristic.put("G", MapG);
    heuristic.put("H", MapH);
    heuristic.put("I", MapI);

    GraphAStar<String> graph = new GraphAStar<String>(heuristic);
    graph.addNode("A");
    graph.addNode("B");
    graph.addNode("C");
    graph.addNode("D");
    graph.addNode("E");
    graph.addNode("F");
    graph.addNode("G");
    graph.addNode("H");
    graph.addNode("I");


    graph.addEdge("A", "B", 2);
    graph.addEdge("A", "C", 3);
    graph.addEdge("A", "D", 5);
    graph.addEdge("B", "E", 4);
    graph.addEdge("C", "F", 2);
    graph.addEdge("D", "E", 3);
    graph.addEdge("D", "F", 3);
    graph.addEdge("E", "G", 2);
    graph.addEdge("F", "H", 3);
    graph.addEdge("G", "H", 5);
    graph.addEdge("G", "I", 2);




    AStar<String> aStar = new AStar<String>(graph);
    for(String path : aStar.Astar("A", "I")){
        System.out.println(path);
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: `Node` class doesn't implement the `Map` interface, so there's no reason to expect casting a `Node` to `Map` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is that you have Node class and you are trying to cast it to Map. Then you have to implement [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) for you Node class.

```
public class Node <T> implements Map { ....
```

Keep on mind this rule:

> Only classes or interfaces (collectively known as Type) from the same
>   type hierarchy can be cast or converted into each other.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html#ixzz4Cu3RXPhy

Comment: Oh i see, since Map is acting like a superclass and Node as a subclass i added the type casting to the methods and classes "<T>" what i forgot is to actually tell the program that they where from the same hierarchy. well is hard to actually express myself but thank you. now it works perfectly